# Is it possible to access sagemaker jupyter notebook from intellij IDE?

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I have deployed a model via jupyter notebook on sagemaker instance.

Now, I am wondering is there any chance to access sagemaker jupyter notebook from intellij IDE?

I am looking for a way to make an environment to work with peers so that I can get code reviews.

I can see I can control aws lambda functions via terminal, but not sure about Jupyter notebook on Sagemaker instance.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA with Python plugin, as well as PyCharm, can connect to [any Jupyter server accessible by the URL](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-jupyter-notebook.html#configure-server:~:text=To%20connect%20to%20any%20running%20Jupyter%20server). DataSpell IDE also [has a similar feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dataspell/creating-and-managing-projects.html#remote). Finally, a [feature request for native Sagemaker support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-444/Connect-to-AWS-SageMaker-notebooks)

Comment: @AndreyResler I will look up what you said! Thank you!

Comment: You can run SageMaker API calls (like start/update notebooks, run processing jobs) from the CLI, but I doubt you would be able to access the instance from an IDE. SageMaker [natively supports Git](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-git-repo.html), and SM Studio supports [notebook sharing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-sharing.html), so maybe options for code reviews?

Comment: @durga_sury I will look it up as well! Thank you for your information :)

Comment: I posted a solution but it was deleted - so here it is as a comment: https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-ssh-helper - the specific use case is covered here: https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-ssh-helper#studio - good luck and let me know how you get on!

Comment: @blackgreen Why was my answer deleted when it solves the problem for the OP?

Comment: @jtlz2 Your solution is what I was looking for. I have no idea why it was deleted.